# Why have HashSet but not Set in C#?

Tags: c#, set, hashset

### Old question

My understanding is that C# has in some sense `HashSet` and `set` types. I understand what `HashSet` is. But why `set` is a separate word? Why not every set is `HashSet<Object>`?

### New question

Why does C# has no generic `Set` type, similar to `Dictionary` type? From my point of view, I would like to have a set with standard lookup/addition/deletion performance. I wouldn't care much whether it is realized with hashes or something else. So why not make a set class that would actually be implemented as a `HashSet` in this version of C# but perhaps somewhat different in a future version?

Or why not at least interface `ISet`?

## Answer

Learned thanks to everyone who answered below: `ICollection` implements a lot of what you'd expect from `ISet`. From my point of view, though, `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable` while sets don't have to be enumerable --- example: set of real numbers between 1 and 2 (even more, sets can be generated dynamically). I agree this is a minor rant, as 'normal programmers' rarely need uncountable sets.

Ok, I think I get it. `HashSet` was absolutely meant to be called `Set` but the word `Set` is reserved in some sense. More specifically, creators of .NET architecture wanted to have a consistent set (sic!) of classes for different languages. This means that every name of the standard class must not coincide with any keyword in the .NET languages. The word `Set`, however, is used in VB.NET which is actually case-insensitive (is it?) so unfortunately there is no room for maneuvre there.

Mystery solved :)

## Epilogue

The new answer by Alex Y. links to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081%28VS.100%29.aspx) which describes  the upcoming .NET 4.0 interface **`ISet`** which behaves pretty much as I thought it should and is implemented by `HashedSet`. Happy end.

Comment: as a side note, there are few [`internal class Set` in the .NET reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c10b234c0932864)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(Your original question about `set` has been answered. IIRC, "set" is the word with the most different meanings in the English language... obviously this has an impact in computing too.)

I think it's fine to have `HashSet<T>` with that name, but I'd certainly welcome an `ISet<T>` interface. Given that `HashSet<T>` only arrived in .NET 3.5 (which in itself was surprising) I suspect we may eventually get a more complete collection of set-based types. In particular, the equivalent of Java's `LinkedHashSet`, which maintains insertion order, would be useful in some cases.

To be fair, the `ICollection<T>` interface actually covers most of what you'd want in `ISet<T>`, so maybe that isn't required. However, you could argue that the core purpose of a set (which is mostly about containment, and only tangentially about being able to iterate over the elements) isn't quite the same as a collection. It's tricky. In fact, a truly mathematical set may not be iterable or countable - for instance, you could have "the set of real numbers between 1 and 2." If you had an arbitrary-precision numeric type, the count would be infinite and iterating over it wouldn't make any sense.

Likewise the idea of "adding" to a set doesn't always make sense. Mutability is a tricky business when naming collections :(

EDIT: Okay, responding to the comment: the keyword `set` is in no way a legacy to do with Visual Basic. It's the operation which *sets* the value of a property, vs `get` which *retrieves* the operation. This has nothing to do with the idea of a set as an operation.

Imagine that instead the keywords were actually `fetch` and `assign`, e.g.

```
// Not real code!
public int Foo
{
    fetch
    {
        return fooField;
    } 
    assign
    {
        fooField = value;
    } 
}
```

Is the purpose clear there? Now the *real* equivalent of that in C# is just

```
public int Foo
{
    get
    {
        return fooField;
    } 
    set
    {
        fooField = value;
    } 
}
```

So if you write:

```
x = y.Foo;
```

that will use the `get` part of the property. If you write:

```
y.Foo = x;
```

that will use the `set` part.

Is that any clearer?

Comment: In fact I still don't get the original thing about set.

Comment: From the linked post the closest I get is that there is some legacy Set word from Visual Basic.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I am familiar with the set/get keyword pair, but I know they are lowercase, and I believe C# is case-sensitive, so I didn't think that to be relevant to the Set class. But Set being a reserved keyword from VB.NET explains it (I didn't know C# and VB are related until now, but now I guess they are)

Comment: I knew about ICollection, but I guess for me as a mathematician collections and sets from the start were very different. Now as I think about it I agree  ICollection is similar to how people actually use sets in programming. However, taking an example from math, sets have more interesting examples. For example, consider the set [0; 1] \union [2; 3) \union [7; +\infty]. This set is easy to program as an ordered set but it can never be programmed as a collection.

Comment: Correction: it can never be programmed as a list, but I suspect that ICollection includes method similar to ToArray(). It could be thought of as a collection which has no way to be iterated through, but I think this is a new idea compared to what people are used to.

Comment: I think I missed the part of your answer where you say the same thing as I do about sets being not necessarily countable. Apologies for repeating it as my invention.

Comment: On mutability and addition -- sets are very dangerous in this respect since real_set.Add(5) as well as real_set.Plus(5) could be understood as the whole set shifted by 5 (that is, the new set whose elements are exactly x+5 for x being an elements of some_set)

Comment: Yup, basically you need to be very clear about what concept of "set" you're talking about. I think I'd always use something like "offset" for the latter operation you're talking about, but I agree that it's a cause of concern.

Comment: In fact, translate(Vector v) would be the math standard... of course it might not play well with i18n.

Comment: **Update** Of course, in 2010 came .NET version 4.0 with an `ISet<T>` interface which is implemented by `HashSet<T>` and a new `SortedSet<T>` class.

Answer (score 6):

The only reason for this seems lack of resources to implement this ideally in .NET 3.5.

.NET 4.0 will include [ISet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081(VS.100).aspx), as well as its new implementation in addition to [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(VS.100).aspx) - [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(VS.100).aspx). Check out the provided links to MSDN library - they're already available in .NET 4.0 beta1.

Comment: Amazing how you found it, thanks! I wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Set`<T>`.  This [BCL team Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/11/09/introducing-hashset-t-kim-hamilton.aspx) has lot's of details on HashSet including a not entirely conclusive discussion on including hash in the name.  I suspect not everyone on the BCL team liked the decision to use the name HashSet`<T>`.

Comment: They say it's because Set is a contextual keyword of get/set pair -- but isn't that lowercase set?

Comment: Upvote- a link to the BCL team blog would of been my answer, but I've just seen the question and you've already answered it.

Comment: I personally like it to be called `Set<T>` leaving the implementation detail (hash) out.

Comment: Well, there is a [`Set<T>`class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c10b234c0932864) which is internal. But it's working like the `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

`set` is a C# language keyword that has been around since version 1.0. Is is used to define the value-assigning part of a property (and `get` is used to implement the value-reading part of a property). In this context you should understand the word 'set' as a verb, as in setting a value.

`HashSet<T>` is a particular implmentation of the mathematical concept of a Set. It was first introduced in .NET 3.5. This blog post by the BCL Team explains more about the reasoning behind it, as well as some clues to why the name is `HashSet<T>` and not just `Set<T>`: http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/11/09/introducing-hashset-t-kim-hamilton.aspx.

In the case of `HashSet<T>` you should understand the word 'set' as a noun.

Comment: I'm not able to solve the clues :) The best I can get is that Set is somehow reserved because of VB.

Comment: Because I know about set as a verb, but I think C# is case-sensitive so why would it be mixed up with Set?

Comment: Set is indeed a keyword in VB.NET. Although C# is case-sensitive, the CLS isn't, so there's a danger that a case-insensitive language (such as VB.NET) would have trouble telling the keyword and the type apart. Even if the compiler can figure it out, developers might become confused. Thus, the Framework Design Guidelines recommend avoiding certain keywords as type names.

`HashSet<T>` was developed to be used from any .NET-based language and not only C#.

Answer (score 3):

Set is a reserved keyword in VB.NET (it's the equivalent to set in C#). VB.NET can use classes/methods/etc with the same name as keywords but they have to be written between square brackets, which it's ugly:

```
Imports Wintellect.PowerCollections 'PowerCollections contains a class called Set'
Public Class Test
    Private _myValue As Integer  

    Public Property MyValue() As Integer
        Get
            Return _myValue
        End Get
        Set ' Set as keyword'
            _myValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function X As [Set](Of Integer)
        Dim a As New [Set](Of Integer) ' Set as class'
        Return a
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: No, sorry, I don't get it. How are C# and VB/.NET related?

Comment: VB.NET and C# are the main languages of .NET, they are almost equivalent in features, they compile to almost the same IL and Microsoft promised to make them closer in the future.
VB.NET community is quite large but you don't see as many questions about VB.NET because many of them can understand C# without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Ah right I understand your question now
Not sure I can 100% see the need for an `ISet<T>`.
I guess the question is which do you see as essential behaviour for a set?
Is it Add,Remove, Contains etc. If so then `ICollection<T>` already provides an interface for that.
If it's set operations such as Union, Intersect, etc then is that something you'd consider generic enough to abstract out to a contract style enforcement?

I have to say I don't know the right answer to this one - I think it's open to debate and I suspect the BCL team may end up putting something like this in a future version but that's up to them. I personally don't see it as massive missing piece of functionality

### Original Post

The BCL doesn't have a Set collection at all, at least not as far as I know.
There a few 3rd party Set libs out there like [Iesi.Collections](https://olex.openlogic.com/packages/iesi-collections)
`HashSet<T>` was introduced in .NET 3.5 to create a fast set collection i.e where you want a collection with no duplicates. It also has typical set operations such as Union and Join.
Check out [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/11/09/introducing-hashset-t-kim-hamilton.aspx) from BCL team on HashSet

You'd typically use it where previously you had to use `List<T>` and check for duplicates when adding.
Adding items to a `HashSet<T>` can also be [significantly faster](http://www.vcskicks.com/hashset.php) than List

Some further details:
Another nice feature of HashSet is that it doesn't throw an exception if you try and add a duplicate it just fails to add the duplicate entry which saves you having to put lots of try.catch blocks around every add - nice :)

Comment: OK, but why not have interface ISet with all those properties and HashSet that implements it? This is how Dictionary works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no `Set<T>` class in the BCL, at least in .NET 3.5 (and not .NET 4.0 either it seems). What would you expect is the need for such a class, anyway?

`HashSet<T>` is itself just an ordinary set data structure that uses hash codes (the `GetHashCode` method of an object) to compare elements. This is simply an efficient way of implementing a set type. (Other methods for checking equality would likely have lower performance.)

Comment: The HashSet uses the GetHashCode to locate elements inside it's buckets. It still compares the elements using Equals, in case two elements have the same HashCode and end up in the same bucket.

Comment: @Noam: Indeed, that is the case. My point was just that GetHashCode is the primary method of comparison. Equals is pretty much used as a "back-up".